# rails 3.2 engines , prepend engine 's layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, layout, rails-engines

I'm looking for a way to inject an engine layout to the main_app layout, I've found this interesting example:

https://github.com/shageman/rails_container_and_engines

but If I add something to `app/engines/web_engine1/app/assets/stylesheets/web_engine1/welcome.css` it doesn't work as expected.

A use case could be:

(main_app) application.css (has global styles e.g the background color)
(page_engine) application.css (inherit (main_app) application.css and add a special color to h1 tags )

Do You have a simple example which can manage this situation?